# How add a link in mail using php

Tags: php

I want to send a mail with url. My url is

```
$request = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

These url is included in mail body,but with these url mail do not send.

My code is

```
$message88 .="<html><body><a href=".$request.".'activate_sale.php?insert_id=$sale_id' style='text-decoration:none;'><font size='3'>Accept</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=".$request.".'reject_sale.php?insert_id=$sale_id' style='text-decoration:none;'><font size='3'>Reject</font></a></body></html>";
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: How could you send emails? i.e via PHP mail function?

Comment: What do you mean by "the mail doesn't send"? The link shouldn't have any effect at all on whether PHP will send a mail, it doesn't care about the content of the mail.

Comment: first you check with normal text it is sending or not  then after try with html!!

Comment: @sємsєм with php mail function

Comment: Well, by default PHP mail function only supports plain text mails. To make life more easier, try to use any library that able to send HTML mail contents.

Comment: @ Blowski  Mail can sent with out these link message content,that mail contain other html mail body,but with these link content mail not send

Comment: with these url i can send mail <a href='http://vestroxinc.com/activate_sale.php?insert_id=$sale_id'>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$request = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";

$message88 ="<html><body><a href='".$request."activate_sale.php?insert_id=$sale_id' style='text-decoration:none;'><font size='3'>Accept</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".$request."reject_sale.php?insert_id=$sale_id' style='text-decoration:none;'><font size='3'>Reject</font></a></body></html>";
```

Comment: I checked the html which is getting correctly now. but earlier not. Mail not sending can be any mail issue. WHat is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error is mail is not get in my inbox,,my server is in goddady,any problem with that?

Comment: So as I told, this is not regarding the html or php issue. Check in your spam or junk folder.